# htaccess "Object not found" CakePhp on XAMP and MAC OS X

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

Probably you have seen these question pop up a lot on Google. However, I went through most of all documents I could find, I still could not fix my current problem.

I still getting this error when I access http://mydomain.com/phpserver/pages/websocket

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Thu May 5 12:09:38 2011
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

However, it works fine with a URL like this: http://mydomain.com/phpserver/index.php/pages/websocket

But of course, the CSS and Javascript are not loaded properly. So the following are what I have been trying to do:

I did modify httpd.conf in the XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc folder. I made sure that the server allow mod_rewrite.

I also add my working directory into this file:

```
Alias /phpserver /Users/username/WebSites/phpserver/webroot/
<Directory "/Users/username/WebSites/phpserver">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes  
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also modified the DocumentRoot configuration so that:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    #XAMPP
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Those are the configurations for the apache

For CakePHP I also "bake" the whole project using the console ./cake bake appname

I checked all .htaccess and they are followed what people on the web recommended. This is the one located at the root of the application

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

And this is the one located inside the webroot folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help! I have spent so much time on this :(

Thanks in advance

---

Edit:
I fixed the problem by adding this into .htaccess inside the webroot folder:
RewriteBase /phpserver/

So it turns out to be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /phpserver/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I did but it still does not work. I even restarted my computer.

Comment: Turn AllowOverride All -> AllowOverride None and restart apache. See if that works.

Comment: Hi Tri.  Can you edit your edit to insert 4 spaces before the <IfModule, so it appears as code?  And even better, if that fixed the problem, post it as an answer to your own question.